# Calculating if this physical scenario is possible in a roulette wheel

Tags: forces, rotation

Would it be possible to calculate if a roulette ball can stay between the numbers in a wheel with some rotational force? Or is there some magnet system in the wheel? The video attached below.

[The ball lands between the numbers](https://youtu.be/3f_uEPOp-qQ)

Comment: The system is too complex to study analytically, so averaging the results of a large set of simulations is probably the only way you can do this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there some software to process this type of simulations?